# Converting PyTorch tensors back into floats

Tags: python, pytorch, floating-point

here's the code i was writing for class

```
def get_avg_info_of_attribute(tensor:torch.Tensor, attribute:int):
    number_of_outcomes = tensor.shape[0] #length of attribute
    unique_values = torch.unique(tensor[:,attribute]) #tuple of unique values
    average_info = 0
    for i in unique_values:
        value_mask = (tensor[:, attribute] == i) 
        positive_outcomes = value_mask.sum().item() #extracting an integer from it
        value_probability = positive_outcomes/number_of_outcomes
        class_counts = torch.bincount(tensor[value_mask, -1]) 
        class_probability = class_counts.float()/positive_outcomes
        class_probability += 1e-11 #was getting nan because of logarithms. this seemed to help
        average_info += value_probability*(-torch.sum(class_probability*torch.log2(class_probability)))
        
    return average_info
```

i originally was using float(class_counts) instead of class_counts.float() or class_counts.item(). i don't really understand the difference between the first two.

the error i got with float(class_counts) is 'ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars'

would appreciate an explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is probably occurring because class_counts is a tensor with more than one element, and you're trying to directly convert it to a Python scalar using `float(class_counts)`, which is not allowed for tensors with more than one element.

Here's something you can do:

```
class_probability = class_counts.float() / positive_outcomes
```

Replace the above line with the following:

```
class_probability = class_counts.float() / positive_outcomes
# Remove zeros
class_probability = class_probability[class_probability.nonzero()]
```

This will remove the zero values from the `class_probability` tensor before applying the logarithmic calculations. This should help you avoid the `ValueError` and perform the calculations correctly.